# Memory leakage: connections are not disposed even after the use of releasebody()

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux

Even after processing the body and releasing it my connections are disposed. I cant use retrieve() as i need to check status code.

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://localhost:8066");
        
public Mono<City> getCityById(Integer id){
    return webClient.get()
            .uri("/cities/" + id)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(clientResponse -> {
                if (clientResponse.statusCode().value() == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()) {
                    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(BadRequestException.class)
                            .flatMap(errorDetails -> Mono.error(new BadRequestException(errorDetails.getMessage())));
                } else if (clientResponse.statusCode().is4xxClientError()) {
                    return clientResponse.bodyToMono(NotFoundException.class)
                            .flatMap(errorDetails -> Mono.error(new NotFoundException(errorDetails.getMessage())));
    
               } 
                Mono<City> val =  clientResponse.bodyToMono(City.class);
                clientResponse.releaseBody();
                return val;
            }       
);
```

Comment: `clientResponse.releaseBody();` returns a `Mono`. Also you can use `retrieve` in combination with `.onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError, response -> ...)` https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-retrieve

Comment: Even after using retrieve() sockets are not closing.

Comment: then we need more debugging details, please produce a small reproducible example.

Comment: fyi the checks you are doing on the status code can be achieved when using `retrieve` by using the `onStatus` operator

Comment: I did implement that using retrieve but the memory leakage problem is still there.

Comment: Is there any way to enable matrix for netty only?